# Dagger 2 error: "RepositoryImpl cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method"

Tags: android, dagger-2

For example, I have following interface:

```
public interface Repository {
    Observable<Pojo> getPojos();
}
```

And its implementation:

```
public class RepositoryImpl implements Repository {

    public RepositoryImpl() { 

    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Pojo> getPojos() {
        return null;
    }   

}
```

Module:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    public AppModule() {

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Repository provideRepositoryImpl() {
        return new RepositoryImpl();
    }

}
```

And component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class })
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);   
}
```

When I trying to build project, I receive error as in question title. What problem in my code?

Comment: Dagger gets injected in the Application class normally where's your inject for the application class?

Answer (score 1):

Read your error carefully (emphasis mine):

> Dagger 2 error: “**RepositoryImpl** cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method”

Generally this means you've tried to `@Inject RepositoryImpl`, not `@Inject Repository`. This is especially important because your Module directly calls the RepositoryImpl constructor rather than letting Dagger create your RepositoryImpl using an `@Inject`-annotated constructor. (If you had, you could make `RepositoryImpl` a parameter of your `@Provides` method or switch to a `@Binds` method, and you have your choice between injecting the interface versus the implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

The way I setup Dagger 2 is in my projects Application I add the injection component. like so.

```
public class NyApplication extends Application {

InjectionComponent component;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setDagger();
}

private void setDagger() {
    component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appComponent(new AppModule())
            .build();
    component.inject(this);
}

public InjectionComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}}
```

and then int my activity whatever it is. I inject on it's onCreate like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Inject
Object object;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);

}}
```

I hope this helps you.